# PHP -> TCP to NODE.JS vs PHP -> HTTP to NODE.JS

Tags: php, node.js, tcp

I currently use TCP the method described here:
[Connection between Node.JS and PHP via UNIX Socket - EPIPE write error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23513791/connection-between-node-js-and-php-via-unix-socket-epipe-write-error)

And I see other people are using HTTP instead here:
[Sending messages from PHP to Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048978/sending-messages-from-php-to-node-js)

Besides the fact the TCP implementation has slightly less code, and no cURL, are there any disadvantages to using the TCP method?
Such as queuing problems for many simultaneous requests or I have no idea, so I'm asking those with experience with this kind of thing if there are any pro's and con's involved between these two implementations of PHP to NODE.JS.

Answers appreciated - silly comments not.